# Nothing is being stored in my "username" variable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Attached below is my code, I've tried adding print statements to troubleshoot but nothing is coming through. This program is supposed to run as a discord bot by the command !roblox (username). It then takes the username and check's it's rank in a group, friends, account age, all through Roblox's API.

```
import discord
import requests

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!roblox'):
        # Get the username from the user input
        username = message.content.split('!roblox ')[1]
        print(username) 
        # Make a request to the Roblox API to get the user's data
        url = f"https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/search?keyword=    {username}&limit=10"
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()

        # Check if the user exists
        if "data" in data and data["data"]:
            user_id = data["data"][0]["id"]

            # Get the user's account age
            url = f"https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/{user_id}"
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()
            created_at = data["created"]

             # Get the user's friend count
             url = f"https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{user_id}/friends/count"
             response = requests.get(url)
             data = response.json()
             friend_count = data["count"]

             # Get the user's role name in the group "United States Army"
             url = f"https://groups.roblox.com/v2/users/{user_id}/groups/roles"
             response = requests.get(url)
             data = response.json()

             role_name = None
             for group in data["data"]:
                 if group["group"]["id"] == 3108077:
                     role_name = group["role"]["name"]
                    break

             # Build the response message
            message = f"**Username:** {username}\n"
            message += f"**Account Age:** {created_at}\n"
            message += f"**Friend Count:** {friend_count}\n"
            message += f"**Role in United States Army:** {role_name}" if role_name else ""

        else:
            message = f"Could not find user {username}."

        # Send the response message
        await message.channel.send(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

I'm not sure why the username variable doesn't have a value. Please help!

Comment: Is `message.content.startswith('!roblox')` true? are you getting inside the if-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split splits a string into parts based on the string you put in as the argument. For example, `"hi there".split(" ")` is splitting "hi there" up by " ", so that will result in `["hi", "there"]`. To get the username, use this:

```py
username = message.content.split(' ')[1]
```

Also, your bot needs the message content intent, enable that in the developer portal and also with this:

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your bot needs access to the message content (message_content intents).
[discord.Message.content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content)
[discord.Intents.message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content)
If you set this, your code should work.